# custom spinner(getting different value)

Tags: java, android

I tried to create to custom spinner and almost succeed. Spinner shows weird values in dropdown scenario but when item is selected i get correct value...the problem is why i am getting weird values?[image: I get the correct value]
[image: during dropdown..weird values]
spinnerActivity.java

```
public class customSpinner extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_spinner);

    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);

    ArrayList<spinner_info> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();


    arrayList1.add(new spinner_info("a"));
    arrayList1.add(new spinner_info("b"));
    arrayList1.add(new spinner_info("c"));
    arrayList1.add(new spinner_info("d"));

    spinner_adapter sAdapter = new spinner_adapter(this,arrayList1);
     sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

spinner_Adapter.java

```
 public class spinner_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<spinner_info> {

public spinner_adapter(Context context,ArrayList<spinner_info> arrayList1) {
    super(context,0,arrayList1);
}




@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    View viewItem = convertView;
    if(viewItem==null)
    {
        viewItem= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(spinner_item,parent,false);
    }

    spinner_info currentinfo=getItem(position);

    TextView name = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item_spinner);
    name.setText(currentinfo.getSub());

    return viewItem;

}
}
```

spinner_Info.java

```
public class spinner_info{
String subject1;

public spinner_info(String subject){
    subject1=subject;
}

public String getSub()      {return subject1;}
}
```

spinner_Item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_spinner" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: looks like default `toString` output .. add `public String toString() { return subject1; }` to your spinner_Info class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayAdapter` basically just calls `toString()` on the value it finds in the array. You're using a custom POJO (`spinner_info`) with one field that's a String, so it's taking your class and calling `toString()` which gives you the fully-qualified class name and the memory address.

Given that your POJO has just the String field, you can just get rid of that POJO and pass the `ArrayAdapter` a list of Strings and your `Spinner` should display them properly. Then when one is selected, you can check the value of the String.

**Implementation**

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();

arrayList1.add("a");
arrayList1.add("b");
arrayList1.add("c");
arrayList1.add("d");

spinner_adapter sAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, arrayList1);

spinner.setAdapter(sAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selection = arrayList1.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

**SpinnerAdapter class**

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public List<String> strings;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strings != null ? strings.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return strings != null ? strings.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

You'll need to set the text of the view in the appropriate methods inside the adapter.

Comment: i need to implement these array of string custom_adopter so that i could change the properties like size,color etc later.

Comment: Added a SpinnerAdapter class to the answer. The layout resource used in `getView` is one shown by the Spinner when something is selected. The layout resource used in `getDropdownView` is the dropdown shown when you tap on the Spinner to select something.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rw2ltjdjsntmkp/customSpinner.rar?dl=0 ) download project and see yourself....and upload here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/request/zT8aDdXVPgjHl7GWUFA2)

Comment: Its k..thank s for help i solved it..u forgot to mention this: TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);

        String text = strings.get(position);
        tv.setText(text);

        return convertView;

Comment: That's why I added the part at the bottom there. Can't expect me to do it all for you. ;)